# How to have three quote marks in gnuplot's oneliner?

Tags: bash, gnuplot, quotes

Assume your pseudocode is where the mistake is with two times using the quotes `"`

```
gnuplot - e "set output 'tmp.png'; set_label(x,text) = sprintf("set label '%s' at cos(%f)", text, x, x)
```

which is wrong.

**How can you have three types of quotes in gnuplot one-liner?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must simply escape the second double quote characters for the shell (not for gnuplot!) with a backslash:

```
gnuplot -e "set output 'tmp.png'; set_label(x,text) = sprintf(\"set label '%s' at cos(%f)\", text, x, x)"
```

Alternatively, you can use gnuplot's mechanism of escaping: use double single quotes to escape one single quote character:

```
gnuplot -e "set output 'tmp.png'; set_label(x,text) = sprintf('set label ''%s'' at cos(%f)', text, x, x)"
```